# Why the weight constraints and dropout function cannot be used in custom layers on Keras

Tags: python, keras, constraints, keras-layer, dropout

I would like to implement dropout and weight constraints in the custom layer. The program did not report an error, but neither did these two functions
The custom layer is:
'''
class Softmax_Decode(Layer):
""" A layer which uses a key to decode a sparse representation into a softmax.

```
Makes it easier to train spiking classifiers by allowing the use of  
softmax and catagorical-crossentropy loss. Allows for encodings that are 
n-hot where 'n' is the number of outputs assigned to each class. Allows
encodings to overlap, where a given output neuron can contribute 
to the probability of more than one class.

# Arguments
    key: A numpy array (num_classes, input_dims) with an input_dim-sized
        {0,1}-vector representative for each class.
    size: A tuple (num_classes, input_dim).  If ``key`` is not specified, then
        size must be specified.  In which case, a key will automatically be generated.
"""
def __init__(self, key=None,size=None,kernel_regularizer=None,kernel_constraint=None,dropout=0.0,**kwargs):
    super(Softmax_Decode, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.key = _key_check(key, size)
    if type(self.key) is dict and 'value' in self.key.keys():
        self.key = np.array(self.key['value'], dtype=np.float32)
    elif type(self.key) is list:
        self.key = np.array(self.key, dtype=np.float32)
    #self._rescaled_key = K.variable(np.transpose(2*self.key-1))
    self._rescaled_key = K.variable(2*np.transpose(self.key)-1)
    self.kernel_regularizer = regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
    self.kernel_constraint = constraints.get(kernel_constraint)
    self.dropout = dropout

def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                  #shape=(input_shape[1], self.key.shape[1]),
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                                  constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
    super(Softmax_Decode, self).build(input_shape)

def call(self, inputs):
    #return K.softmax(K.dot(2*(1-inputs),self._rescaled_key))
    return K.softmax(K.dot(2*inputs-1, self._rescaled_key))

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0],self.key.shape[0])

def get_config(self):
    config={
    'kernel_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.kernel_regularizer),
    'kernel_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.kernel_constraint)
    }
    base_config = super(Softmax_Decode, self).get_config()
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + [('key', self.key)])
```

'''
main code:

```
model.add(Softmax_Decode(key,kernel_constraint=MinMaxNorm(min_value=0, max_value=1.0, rate=1.0, axis=0),dropout=0.3))
```

Would you help me? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the problem? What do you mean cannot be used? Your code is not using the dropout parameters or self.kernel so of course these will not do anything

Comment: Thank you for answering me. Is the dropout not applied to the custom layer? Could you give me some advice to improve it? The ultimate goal is to use dropout and weight constraints in the custom layer.

Comment: For dropout you need to use the keras.backend.dropout function in your code. I am not sure what you mean with using the weight constraints, did you notice that your call function does not use any weights?

Comment: I have noticed that there is no weight function in the code, but the results of the parameters include the weight of this layer (I also have doubts about this). The weight constraints refer to limiting the parameters to a range.  "For dropout, you need to use the keras.backend.dropout function in your code"，I try to improve it based on your suggestion. Thank you so much!!

Comment: The layer has weights because you used add_weight, but these weights are not used in any computation

Comment: Oh, that's it! The code just use "K.softmax(K.dot(2*inputs-1, self._rescaled_key))" for last layer's computation? Could you explain more? Thank you so..so much!